# what does this bash script line of code means

Tags: bash, shell

i am new to shell scripting and i found following line of code in a given script.

could someone explain me what does the following lines of codes means

1. `_filecount=echo ${_filelist} | wc -w | awk '{ print $1 }'`
2. `printk "archiveWLS(): ${_filecount} file(s)"`

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Is it printk or printf ?
And make it **Linux Shell Scripting**

Comment: **windows** scripting? Really?

Comment: this script given to me is written on windows and then using dos2unix it was translated to unix script. so my thought was this is in a format that windows understand.

Comment: dos2unix takes care of the terminating characters that are used by these platforms.[link]http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html  

**that is all.Try reading the man page**

Comment: This script is syntactically valid shell script, but broken. It is a syntactically valid NT command script/batch file, but from its form clearly never meant to be one (and also broken). It doesn't appear to be written as a powershell script. It is not a valid wscript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
_filecount=echo ${_filelist} | wc -w | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

`wc -w`: wc is word-count, wordcount counts words, lines, characters and so on, -w only outputs the word count.

The output is piped to awk, to print only the first word of output. If you use

```
 wc -w FILE
```

the filename would be printed, and it would make sense to strip it away with awk. Doing it with a piped output, where there is no filename, is superflous.

As assignment, the line should instead be:

```
_filecount=$(echo ${_filelist} | wc -w )
```

Without $(...) or backticks, it doesn't work, and filecount is just assigned the word "echo". Seems like a poorly written script.

printk isn't defined in bash, nor is it a well established gnu programm from the coreutils.

Maybe it is defined in the script itself.

Answer (score 1):

It stores the number of words in _filelist variable into _filecount.
Elaboration :

`_filecount=```echo ${_filelist} | wc -w | awk '{ print $1 }'``
you have to wrap it under `s,for this is the rule.

**echo** gives out what's stored in **_filelist** to **wc**.

**wc (word counter )** receives  it (this passing of intermediate result is called piping),and because it's invoked with a **-w** option,  it already gives out only the number of words to **awk**,and keeps the count of lines and characters to itself.

**awk** in turn prints out first column of what's supplied to it ( awk '{ print $1 }'`).

**wc** only supplies 1 column here,i.e. the word count,so calling **awk** is redundant actually.

`printf "archiveWLS(): ${_filecount} file(s)"`

substitutes the value of _filecount into the string and gives it out to the standard output stream,which happens to be your shell output window.
That's it.

Answer (score 0):

What this script does is, essentially, nothing.

```
_filecount=echo ${_filelist} | wc -w | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

This line is syntactically valid but not likely to be correct.

Because `echo` appears where it does it is being interpreted as a temporary variable assignment that exists only for the duration of the following command, Thus, the environment variable `_filecount` will have a value of `echo` during the run of the command stored in the variable `_filelist`; since, I imagine, `_filelist` doesn't contain a command name and, instead, contains the name of one or more non-executable files, you will get a `command not found` error.

The rest of the line is irrelevant. Since the `${_filelist}` command output nothing to stdout, nothing was redirected to `wc -w`. `wc` will report that 0 words werre counted and this value will be passed to `awk`, which will strip the leading whitespace.

What you probably meant to say was more like

```
_filecount=$(echo ${_filelist} | wc -w | awk '{ print $1 }')
```

Which will execute the `echo` pipeline and store the result in the `_filecount` variable.

It isn't really a good idea to store a file list in a space-delimited string like this (for one thing, files can have spaces in their names), instead use a `bash` array, like this:

```
_filelist=("file1.txt" "file2.txt")
```

You can expand this to the list of files with `"${_filelist[@]}"`, all properly quoted, and you can now obtain the count of files this way:

```
_filecount=${#_filelist[@]}
```

Which is much faster (executes in-process instead of calling external utilities) and more reliable (doesn't rely on "one file is one word" semantics).

As for this line:

```
printk "archiveWLS(): ${_filecount} file(s)"
```

Since there is no bash builtin called `printk` and there is no standard utility called `printk`, the result is likely to be:

```
-bash: printk: command not found
```

You could have used `printf` for this:

```
printf "archiveWLS(): ${_filecount} file(s)"
```

And the output would be

```
archiveWLS(): 0 file(s)
```

Where `0` is the value of `_filecount`.

Although, it would be nicer to say:

```
printf 'archiveWLS(): %s file(s)\n' "${_filecount}"
```

Which will output the same as the above, also include a newline at the end and be easier to maintain.